# Remove space above displaymath at start of preview environment

Tags: math-mode, preview

Here is a minimal code example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{preview}%\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\[a=b=c\]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result, with unexpected space on top. With `\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}` uncommented, this space is removed, but I don't want to globally change `\baselineskip` : only remove the space only if `\displaymath` is found at the start of the preview environment.

[image: preview displaymath unexpected space]

Comment: @Mico `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}` as no effect for low height formulas like `\[a=b=c\]` and other problem is that I need to use something like this `begin{preview}\input{content}\end{preview}` and I want to `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}` only if a `\displaymath` is found at the beginning of content.

Comment: @Mico I've just retested `\begin{preview}\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\[a=b=c\]\end{preview}` and top space is still there.

Comment: @Mico Did you make a test with `\begin{preview}\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\[ x = a \]\end{preview}` and with `\begin{preview}\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\[ x = \frac{a}{b} \]\end{preview}` ? In the first case I still get an unexpected top space, but not in the second case. (I'm using Texlive 2020)